# Formatting lost when using .replaceWith(textContent)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml, replacewith

I'm trying to move a div "up" a level and get rid of a blockquote. As you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnpb6chf/5/), when you click "Change", the bold font is not preserved. I have also tried using innerHTML and innerText instead of textContent but neither worked. Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
    <div id="outerdiv">
    <blockquote><div id="innerdiv"><b>Hello </b>Text 1</div></blockquote>
    </div>
<span onclick="removeblockquotes(this)">Change</span>
</html>
```

And the JS:

```
function removeblockquotes(e)
{for (const b of document.querySelectorAll('blockquote')) {
  if (!b.closest('div')?.parentElement.closest('div')) {
    b.replaceWith(b.textContent);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `outerHTML` of the container to the `innerHTML` container, thereby removing the container but preserving the markup inside:

```js
for (const b of document.querySelectorAll('blockquote')) {
  if (!b.closest('div')?.parentElement.closest('div')) {
    b.outerHTML = b.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="outerdiv">
  <blockquote>
    <div id="innerdiv"><b>Hello </b>Text 1</div>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Another approach that'll preserve listeners, by iterating through the children and appending each:

```js
for (const b of document.querySelectorAll('blockquote')) {
  if (!b.closest('div')?.parentElement.closest('div')) {
    while (b.children.length) b.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', b.children[0]);
    b.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="outerdiv">
  <blockquote>
    <div id="innerdiv"><b>Hello </b>Text 1</div>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```